# How do I change the shape or look of jquery UI controls?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm working on a project that needs a lot of draggable items on one droppable place, I know how to create draggable and droppable items with the various options,  but what I'd like to do is give these a custom look. Is there a way to do this? I've bbeen searching google for 'jquery change draggable shape' and other varients with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how much customization you need. If you just need a couple CSS tweaks, [then](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback):

> Draggable elements gets a class of
>   `ui-draggable`
>   During drag the element also gets a class of
>   `ui-draggable-dragging`

So you can could key your changes on `.ui-draggable-dragging` and whatever other selectors you have to narrow it down.

If you want to do something that requires more than just a couple CSS tweaks, then you can render the whole draggable version yourself with the [`helper` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback):

> Allows for a helper element to be used for dragging display. Possible values: 'original', 'clone', Function. If a function is specified, it must return a DOMElement.

So something like this would offer a lot of flexibility:

```
$(...).draggable({
    //...
    helper: function(e) {
        return $('a bunch of pretty HTML');
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the ability to change the look of all of jQuery ui's styles with css. They even have a theme generator to make it easy to customize the look [here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Comment: That doesn't really answer the specific question of customising the draggable helper shape

Answer (score 0):

I remember [using this technique](http://webdevel.blogspot.com/2008/09/jquery-ui-draggables-helper-css-class.html) to add a custom class to the cloned drag helper a while back.

Haven't tried with a recent jquery ui release but that should still work.

Then you can apply css to your custom class.

If you really want to go crazy, you can also add other html elements inside the ui.helper element when the start event fires. Just use the standard jquery append, prepend, whatnot..